# Using stopAtFirst in PHP VerbalExpressions Business Readable language expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use the Verbal Expressions to extract data from

```
<p> | A<a href="https://t.me/ATHcoinEth">ll Time High Community Chat $ATH<br>

</a><br>

A<a href="https://t.me/ATHcoinEth">ll Time High </a>Buy!<br>

</p>

<p> 0.07 ETH ($127.61)<br>

</a><br>

 0x96f7…89a6 | Txn<br>

✅ New Holder<br>

 Market Cap $52,537</p>

<p> Chart   ✨ Trade<br>

 Event<a href="https://etherscan.io/address/0x96f7bb6b05c65bfc894acfd73a75254dbdc189a6">s  Trendin</a>g<a href="https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc8c35dab30caf5c6d5d422e51bf5c88646eefe5b64f8e09e400a93af523345b"> hr</a>ef=<b>"https://t</b>.me/ETHTRENDING/<b>106566</b>1"&gt;<a href="https://dexscreener.com/ethereum/0xc300545b59cce388c29227c0c9269139024df039">a&gt;</a><a>href=</a><a href="https://flooz.xyz/trade/0x70c85f3f74110f26478baf8bbd0ac377ca4288f7?network=eth&amp;refId=HtwiZx">"http</a>s://t.me/BuyBotTracker"&gt;</a><br></p>
```

I am using the verbal expression

`'start, then " |", something, then "<br> </a><br>", end'`

However `<br> </a><br>` appears multiple times in the text so I would like to stop at the first occurance of the text, how can I do this as nothing that I have tried seems to work

Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks so defficient, why not use normal regular expressions?

Comment: It seems like you need lazy quantifier. On first glance, I didn't notice support for it in mentioned library. Plus, regex for this case shouldn't be that "hard" to use external library for its construction. On the other hand, this is clearly html block, so consider using specialized parser, as regexes are well-known to be a wrong tool for html parsing.

Comment: I am not a regex expert, so this provided the easiest starting point for me as a proof of concept for what I needed to do